# Connect to remote TeamViewer computer desktop via MacOS terminal command line

Tags: remote-desktop

How can I launch a TeamViewer remote desktop session to a remote computer from the MacOS command line, assuming that I know the Partner ID of the remote computer?

I already found documentation of command line parameters [here](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Command-line-parameters/ta-p/34447), but there's no MacOS instructions for launching a remote session, only PC instructions.  Yes, I know the document says that command line arguments work for both PC and Mac, but there's obviously no `TeamViewer.exe` on a Mac so I think the main question is where is the Mac equivalent to `TeamViewer.exe`?

BTW, I want to do this so that I can set up dock icons for each remote computer so that I can connect to them with one click on the dock, without the hassle of opening up TeamViewer to pick the remote client.  After I figure out how to launch a remote desktop session from the command line, the next step will be to figure out how to launch a command line via a dock icon, but that's presumably well-documented via Google! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To connect to Teamviewer through the command line in MacOS, pass the arguments as follow (substitute `xxxxxxxx` with the target id, and yyyy with the target password:

```
/Applications/TeamViewer.app/Contents/MacOS/TeamViewer -i xxxxxxxx -P yyyy -ac 1
```

---

> `-ac` options:
>
> - 0: full access
> - 1: confirm all
> - 2: view and show
> - 3: custom
> - 9: undefined

---

The first time you run the command, you may be asked to allow the Terminal in your System Preferences > Security. (as well as TeamViewer itself). Just follow and enter the command again.

[image]

Comment: This does not work for me with Teamviewer 15 on Mojave.  It just launches the GUI and does not try to connect.